# How to count a raster's pixels with a certain value inside a given rectangle in C++ with GDAL?

Tags: c++, raster, gdal

In C++ is there a function to count all the pixels with a certain value inside a given rectangle (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), using GDAL library? Or I'll have to read each block and count them all pixel by pixel? I have searched, but only found a few Python scripts that do that.

I did it for myself (it's a boolean raster - 0/1 - and I'm counting the "1" pixels), but the result is different from that given in GRASS GIS r.report function (via QGIS).

```
long long openTIF(string ftif,double x0,double y0,double x1,double y1) {
    long long sum = 0;
    GDALDataset *poDataset;
    GDALAllRegister();
    poDataset = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(ftif.c_str(),GA_ReadOnly);
    if (poDataset == NULL) {
        cout << "Error reading raster '" << ftif << "'\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    int tx=poDataset->GetRasterXSize(),
        ty=poDataset->GetRasterYSize();
    double geoTransf[6], rx0=0, ry0=0, rx1=0, ry1=0;
    if (poDataset->GetGeoTransform(geoTransf) == CE_None) {
        rx0 = geoTransf[0];
        ry0 = geoTransf[3]-ty*geoTransf[1];
        rx1 = geoTransf[0]-tx*geoTransf[5];
        ry1 = geoTransf[3];
    } else {
        exit(2);
    }
    int nBlockXSize,nBlockYSize;
    GDALRasterBand *poBand;
    poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand(1);
    poBand->GetBlockSize(&nBlockXSize,&nBlockYSize);
    uint32_t i;
    int y,
        col0 = round((rx0-x0)/geoTransf[5]),
        col1 = round((rx0-x1)/geoTransf[5]),
        row0 = round((ry1-y1)/geoTransf[1]),
        row1 = round((ry1-y0)/geoTransf[1]);
    CPLErr error;
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t*)CPLMalloc(nBlockXSize*nBlockYSize);
    GDALDataType type = poBand->GetRasterDataType();
    if (type == GDT_Byte) {
        cout << "Byte" << endl;
    }
    for (y=row0; y<row1; y++) {
        error = poBand->ReadBlock(0,y,data);
        if (error > 0) {
            cout << "Error reading data block.\n";
            exit(3);
        }
        for (i=col0; i<col1; i++) {
            sum += (uint8_t)data[i];
        }
    }
    CPLFree(data);
    return sum;
}
```

For this given raster, and the given coordinates (precision %.8f), GRASS GIS r.report function is reporting 28096011 pixels with value 1, while my sum is giving 28094709 (difference = -1302). With other coordinates r.report gives 5605458, my sum gives 5604757 (difference = -701). Any idea what may be going on?

EDIT: Since my sum was always smaller than GRASS GIS r.report, I though of including the last row and column, changing the lines

```
    for (y=row0; y<row1; y++) {
        for (i=col0; i<col1; i++) {
```

to

```
    for (y=row0; y<=row1; y++) {
        for (i=col0; i<=col1; i++) {
```

but now, with another set of coordinates, r.report gives 249707, while my sum gives 250157 (difference = +450).

Comment: Make a raster with all `1`s, you'll soon see who is right and why the other is wrong.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, I've done that and could see that turning the `<=` back to `<` the calculation was exactly the same as GRASS GIS. It doesn't explain, however, why I got different results in the first trial.

Comment: I'm not an expert on GDAL or GRASS GIS however I notice you are rounding your column and rows. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @TinfoilPancakes I need to round, because I'm translating a `float` into an `int` after a division. If I don't round, I'll get only the integer part of the division result, which could be like a `floor` or a `ceiling` (depending on the hemisphere), or even something worst, if it did the cast into `int` in the beginning of a complex operation.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a rounding error, you need to round down your column and row indexes. It's easier to reason if you think about every raster pixel as a rectangular region. For example, first pixel of your raster spans from `(x, y)` to `(x + width, y + height)`.

```
rx = geoTransf[0];
rx_size = geoTransf[1]; // you got geoTransf[1] and geoTransf[5] swapped!
ry = geoTransf[3];    
ry_size = geoTransf[5];
// assert, that geoTrans[2] and geoTrans[4] are zero

col_first = floor((x0 - rx) / rx_size));
col_last = floor((x1 - rx) / rx_size));
row_first = floor((y0 - ry) / ry_size));
row_last = floor((y1 - ry) / ry_size));

for (int y = row_first; y <= row_last; ++y) {
    poBand->ReadBlock(col_first, y, data);
    for (int x = 0; x <= col_last - col_first; ++x) {
         data[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was out of town and couldn't test your solution or give you the points you probably deserved.